# NOT statement in where Clause in SQL Server Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query , where the results are as expected but the query is really slow. The below is just an example

```
SELECT ispending, isviewable, iscomparable, ID
FROM tableA
WHERE
    name = 'Karen' 
    AND NOT ((ispending = 'F' AND isviewable = '0') OR
             (ispending = 'T' AND iscomparable = '0') OR
             (ispending = 'T' AND iscomparable IS NULL AND isviewable = '0') OR
             (ispending IS NULL AND iscomparable = '0'))
```

How to achieve the same result but not using the 'NOT' statement in the where clause?

I tried changing the not to be within the clause

```
WHERE (ispending != 'F' AND isviewable != '0') OR
      (ispending != 'T' AND iscomparable != '0') OR
      (ispending != 'T' AND iscomparable IS NOT NULL AND isviewable != '0') OR
      (ispending IS NOT NULL AND iscomparable !='0')
```

but the expected results are different.

Comment: typically when you reverse the conditions you have to change and's to or's and vice versa.  With the nesting I am not sure that is all you need but it might be worth starting there.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger I did change the OR to AND as well, still wasnt getting the expected results.

Comment: did you change all of them?  And why do you think doing this will speed it up?  Did something in the Execution Plan indicate that?

Comment: Does the table has any indexes?  Is it doing a clustered index scan?

Comment: What makes you think `NOT` is the issue? In fact as soon as you add `OR` you can run into performance issues - which can sometimes be solved with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I cannot use union as the statement i have is build inside a much complex sql.  As far as the scan goes, It was using clustered scan but for some reason with that filter , It was taking longer time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're second code block is quite close.  De Morgan's law guides in trying to switch operands on boolean operations.

The code is correct to switch `=` with `!=` (the negation of the `=`).  But you will also need to negate conjunctions/disjunctions.  In essence:  `AND` becomes `OR` and vice versa.

```
WHERE (ispending != 'F' OR isviewable != '0') AND
      (ispending != 'T' OR iscomparable != '0') AND
      (ispending != 'T' OR iscomparable IS NOT NULL OR isviewable != '0') AND
      (ispending IS NOT NULL OR iscomparable != '0')
```

Now we have the logical equivalent.